# Best way to return array of certain length

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# from C programming background, sorry for probably a basic question. I'm trying to find the best way to return an array of values from a method.

In C, we can do either of the following:

1. `void myFuction(double[] inputA, int lenA, double* outputA)` : the function gets the input array "inputA" of length "lenA" elements, and returns the "outputA" pointer which is allocated memory before the call to "myFunction" and has got populated in the function "myFunction".
2. `double* myFunction (double[] inputA, int lenA)` : alternatively, be allocated memory inside "myFucntion" based on a desired length, gets populated, and returned as "return outputA".

What's the best way to do this in C#?

Comment: neither way. Just use `double[]` for both in- and out-values. There´s little use on using `*` in C#. So you should use `double[] MyFunction(double[] input, int len)`.

Comment: ref in c# is similar to pointer in c++, more info here https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/ref-keyword

Comment: [`Array.Copy(input, output, desiredLength)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Array_System_Int32_), if you only want to copy the elements from input to output

Comment: All arrays in .NET are *"reference types**; even arrays of value types like `double`.  So, when you pass an array into a function as a parameter, you are passing it as a reference.  If the array changes in the function, then those changes will be observable to the caller when the function returns.  Now, if the function logically *returns an array*, then you should *return an array*.   I would declare the function as `double[] myFunction(double[] inputsA, int lenA)`.  Unlike C or C++, you don't need to worry who allocated memory and who is responsible for freeing the memory.

Comment: You may even want to learn about `Span<T>` too.

Comment: ref is not similar to a c++ pointer. you cannot do "ref double" and expect the same outcome you would get from double*. c# does not natively turn a pass by ref into a memory pointer (e.g. usable array) like c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c# allows for both of these methods as well, however arrays are denoted with [] even in returns instead of the * pointer.

```
double[] myFunction(double[] inputA, int lenA)
{
   double[] output = new double[lengthOfArray];
   ...
   return output;
}
```

Alternatively, c# allows for an "out" parameter that can be used in a similar manner.

```
 void myFunction(double[] inputA, int lenA, out double[] output)
 {
      ...
      output = ...
      //OR
      output[0] = 1; //replace 0 with index #
 }
```

Both are acceptable practices, with the first example being the more common way to do it in c# for readable and organization.

Comment: It's pretty rare that an out parameter for a reference type is needed, though.

Comment: @Flydog57 true, I actually even consider it bad practice in most cases.  If you need an out parameter (or multiples), it always seems to make more sense to make yourself a new class that you can return instead.

Comment: One problem with `out double[] output` is that most folks don't really understand what it means - double indirection (akin to `**` or, even more, `*&` in C++) tends to confuse C# programmers.

Answer (score 3):

> What's the best way to do this in C#?

Pointers are almost never used directly in C#, so the idiomatic signature would use arrays:

```
double[] myFunction (double[] inputA, int lenA)
```

but note that in C# you can also get the length of an array very easily (`int len = inputA.Length`), so `lenA` may not be needed unless you want to support processing a *subset* of the array.

As you progress, you'll find that other data structures like `List` and interfaces like `IEnumerable` may be preferable depending on your use case (i.e. you may decide that the function should just return an iterable collection without specifying the actual *type* of that collection).

As a side note (and from someone who went from C++ to C# myself), the best thing you can do is NOT think of C# as an "extension" or "alternative" to C++. While the syntax and types are very similar, C# as a managed language does many fundamental things very differently, so you may be limiting yourself if you just try to "port" C++ code to C#. Try to think of it as a brand new language and framework with some syntax overlap.